# What does the LY number shown in the Power overview mean?

Tags: elite-dangerous

The overview screen of a Power has tabs for preparation, expansion and control. Each of these tabs has a list of systems that are currently being prepared, expanded to and fortified. Next to each system there is a LY number. Up until now I assumed that this number indicated the distance from the Power's HQ, since that distance is significant when it comes to the effort that has to be spent to prepare/expand/fortify. Today I realized that my assumption was wrong.

For instance, Karsuki Ti is 16.42 LY away from Cubeo (Aisling Duval's HQ), but the control tab in the Power overview screen shows the number 85.5 LY.

So what exactly does this mysterious LY number mean?

(FWIW, I consulted the Power Play manual, but could not find any information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just flew to Cubeo and now the LY number for Karsuki Ti is 16.4 - as I would have expected in the first place.

So the answer to my question is that apparently the LY number shown in the Power overview screen is the distance from my current location.

Whether or not this is useful is something that I still have to meditate upon.

Comment: It can be useful to know which system is closest. When I'm undermining, I'll generally head to the closest Control system to turn my kills into merits, for instance. If you're trying to pick which system to go do a thing in, it's very helpful to know the travel distance from where you are at the moment.

Answer (score -3):

The acronym "**LY**" stands for **L**ight **Y**ears.

Comment: While correct, you do not add any new information to the already provided answer.

Comment: I know that LY means light years - I thought this was obvious from how I wrote the question. Notice keywords such as "distance" and "away".